# Apple APNS Device Token

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

We have table where Apple Device tokens are stored. This tables are different for testing and and for live application. I want to update this database manually with my iPhone device token for testing purpose.

Is there anyway I can read the device token from my iPhone.

Note: I do not hava MAC machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tutorial here of how to get the device token, however it requires that your test application be added some code for you to run.

[Tutorial link](http://ameyashetti.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/apple-push-notification-service-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

If in case you have the code, try putting a log for the device token in the
    **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** and then check the log in your phone using a console app.